# Foreign key reference the following error is showing : the columns in the table 'table' do not match an existing primary key or UNIQUE constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `ProbCodes` and `WorkOrders`

`ProbCodes`:

- Primary key : `ProbCodeID`
- Column      : `ProblemCode`

`WorkOrders`:

- Primary key : `WorkOrderId`
- Column      : `ProblemCode`

**My question is :**

How can I create a foreign key reference between `ProblemCode` in `ProbCodes`  and `ProblemCode` in `WorkOrders`?

Comment: Don't - use `ProbCodeID` in `WorkOrders` instead.  Foreign keys should almost always reference the primary key, not a surrogate key.  If you cannot change the structure then just go without a foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this :

ALTER TABLE ProbCodes
ADD CONSTRAINT UK_CO UNIQUE (ProblemCode)

ALTER TABLE WorkOrders
ADD 
FOREIGN KEY (ProblemCode) REFERENCES ProbCodes(ProblemCode);

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I said in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

By putting a UNIQUE constraint on ProblemCode in ProbCodes.

The error message says it all.   The Foreign Key in WorkOrders has to reference either a Primary Key or Unique column in ProbCodes.   Otherwise, if there are duplicate ProblemCodes in ProbCodes, how can SQL know which row to reference in the parent table?